# Mysql query with implicit datatype conversion returns incorrect results

Tags: mysql, sql, char, numbers, implicit-conversion

mysql has an automatic, convenient number to char (and vice versa) conversions in its SQL query syntax which is behaving dangerously.

consider a table with userid varchar PK

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid     | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| cachetime  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| outputjson | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

the bug is: Any number between 1538993648784210100 and 1538993648784210199 passed as userid gives the same result.

```
mysql> select userid from test_cache where userid = 1538993648784210100;
+---------------------+
| userid              |
+---------------------+
| 1538993648784210176 |
| 1538993648784210178 |
+---------------------+
```

When I explicitly surround userid with quotes it works and returns the right now for those 2 userids.

Comment: any particular reason you're using a text field to store numbers in the first place?

Comment: No reason. But have a legacy code base and such queries work for most inputs.

Comment: What is dangerous is relying on implicit conversion.  How MySQL works is well-documented and standard behavior for databases.

Comment: if you want good apples (varchar) from MySQL don't ask for comparable fruits like pears (int), with other words use the correct datatype when quering like @GordonLinoff says.. "But have a legacy code base and such queries work for most inputs" It might "work" but implicit conversion when not using the correct datatypes can also cause MySQL optimizer not using indexes..

Comment: Would expect an error  for casting overflows and not return incorrect results like these. Also if it allows a number to be input for Char, what are the rules it uses to cast? Is that documented? Of course the table needs to be corrected with correct datatype. But why is it allowing such queries to be written and since it's allowing that, what are the rules it follows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need numeric sorting capabilities on the `userid` column (e.g. `BETWEEN`), then this column should be a numeric type.  I suggest using `DECIMAL(30)` for this column.  Then, incoming numeric values should sort correctly against this column in your table.

You have several problems now.  One is that you are comparing `userid` against *numeric* literals, which means there will be some perhaps exotic casting rules firing under the hood.  You don't want that, and you also don't want to compare numbers against a text column.  Use `DECIMAL` and you can fix both problems at once.

Comment: Agreed on column data type.  Wondering what casting rules are at play for the query to be returning such weird results. It works well for small numbers even other 18 digit numbers.

Comment: @sridharparasuraman If all values being passed in happen to be 18 digits, then your query might work, because then the text numbers would sort correctly.  The casting rules from numbers to text is complicated, and the best thing might be to just fix your table design.

Comment: Sorting is not my concern. My issue is a primary key lookup returning multiple rows. It's obvious there is some casting going on. Curious what are the casting rules.